# What does RESSOL stand for?

Tags: notation, math-history

Does anybody know what the acronym RESSOL, which is another name for the [Tonelli-Shanks Algorithm)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm#cite_note-4), stand for? I would say that it might mean something like "Residue Solver", but I can not find any sources on that.

Comment: I would guess RESSOL is a particular software that implements the Tonelli-Shanks Algorithm.  If so, you should use the name RESSOL only if you are using that software.

Comment: ["RESSOL (for residue solver or something)"](https://www.nctm.org/tmf/library/drmath/view/51513.html)

Comment: D.Shanks often gave 6-letter acronyms to algorithms (not only his own; for example, [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction_factorization) was called BRIMOR in his paper on the SQUFOF algorithm - guess why). So I would look through his works for the matter...